# How to get domain forest of remote machine connected through VPN for AD authentication

Tags: c#, vb.net, active-directory

I want to access the domain forest of the domain on which I am logged in through VPN.

for instance, My computers domain is 'A', I am logged in to domain 'B' through VPN. The domain B has one more child domain/domain in same forest as 'C'. I want to access this list of domain i.e. domain-B and domain-C in the program running on domain-A for AD authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing you need is (in VB):
`Dim myForest As Forest = Forest.GetForest(New DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, "yourActiveDirectoryServer.tld", "administrator", "yourPassword"))`

You will be able to access for information about the domain with the object `myForest`.